# sudo in CentOS 6.1 does not preserve command aliases as sudo elsewhere does?

Tags: centos, sudo, tcsh

On a stock CentOS 6.1 installation, if I start in my user shell (tcsh) with all my usual command aliases and do what I normally do (in other versions of Linux, and Mac OS X) to get a root shell,

```
sudo tcsh
```

my command aliases are **not** preserved.  This is **not** the behavior I see with sudo on other operating systems, including older versions of RHEL (from which CentOS is derived).  I've tried different variations in CentOS 6.1, such as

```
sudo -i tcsh
sudo tcsh -m
sudo -i tcsh -m
```

which by my reading of the sudo and tcsh man pages, should make it behave more like a login shell and presumably do things like interpret my .cshrc file, but nothing has worked.  My default shell is /bin/tcsh in /etc/passwd; I've tried switching root's entry in /etc/passwd to also use /bin/tcsh (the default was /bin/bash), but it didn't make any difference.

I guess this behavior could be controlled by something in /etc/sudoers, but my /etc/sudoers is the stock file installed by CentOS 6.1, and comparing it to (e.g.) Mac OS X 10.6's /etc/sudoers file doesn't immediately reveal an obvious setting that would control this particular behavior.

I'm stumped at this point and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tcsh, aliases are local to the shell instance that they're defined in.  You have to arrange for them to be redefined in each subshell.  When tcsh starts it reads commands from `$HOME/.tcshrc` (or `$HOME/.cshrc` if that doesn't exist); presumably you have your aliases set here.

The command `sudo -i` "simulates an initial login" by setting `$HOME` (and various other environment variables) to that of the target user.

Further, [recent versions](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/devel-old.html#1.7.4b2) of sudo remove `$HOME` from the environment if the option `env_reset` is present in `/etc/sudoers`.

So, to make the root shell source the `.tcshrc` of the user invoking sudo, use `sudo -s`, and add the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults env_keep += HOME
```

Alternatively, you could add the following to `/root/.tcshrc`:

```csh
if ( $?SUDO_USER ) then
    source ~$SUDO_USER/.tcshrc
endif
```

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to this. I tested the first solution (env_keep) but it did not seem to work on my CentOS system. The second solution did, however. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you sudo, you are entering a root shell, rather than your own. You could add your aliases to /root/.cshrc in order for the aliases to be available when you sudo.

Comment: Yes, I know, but sudo on other systems _do_ cause aliases (and perhaps other aspects of the user environment) to be read.  I edited my question to clarify this point; sorry I wasn't clear enough about the key issue.